# too many values to unpack (expected 2) when i'm using filter()

Tags: python, django, date, filter, django-queryset

I have a project in django 1.8 and I want to extract the `date_start` field to get a year and then create a range in what year the event occurs. Then pass it all to `SelectDateWidget` in the form:

```
date_start = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2018)))
```

But I recived: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Here is problematic part of my code:

```
context['years'] = models.Booking.objects.filter('date_start')
```

Here is all code from my view:

```
class BookingListView(ListView, FormView):
    model = models.Booking
    form_class = BookingForm
    queryset = models.Booking.objects.order_by('-date_start')
    paginate_by = 80
    template_name = 'events/archive_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
    date_field = 'date_start'
    allow_future = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookingListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['mode'] = 'archive'
        context['form'] = BookingForm()
        context['years'] = models.Booking.objects.filter('date_start')
        print(context['years'])
        return context
```

Comment: include the full error traceback in the question

Comment: Unless you post the full traceback to your error, no one will be able to help you just by looking at 2 lines of code and one possible error string unrelated to any line number/function call/parameter values etc

Comment: Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using string `"date_start"`, instead of variable `date_start`. Change your code to this and it should work.

```
context['years'] = models.Booking.objects.filter(date_start)
```

Comment: Really, how is this supposed to work with `.filter`?

Comment: Then post more of your code, and full traceback. This was an obvious, easy to fix error, but there might be more in your code.

Comment: You must filter by models.Booking.objects.filter(field=<date_start>)